# Webpack's `parser.hooks.callAnyMember` not getting called

Tags: webpack, hook, webpack-plugin

I'm trying to build a plugin for webpack which goes through each file, analyzes if the function `t` (for translations) is being used then gets the first parameter (which should be a string) and writes it and all of the findings to a json array (at the same time as building).

I've managed to create a "virtual" dependency based on the resolverFactory, although I'm pretty sure that will need more work later on, but I got stuck in a hook which never gets called.

```
    compiler.hooks.normalModuleFactory.tap('TranslationsPlugin', (factory) => {
        factory.hooks.parser.for('javascript/auto').tap('TranslationsPlugin', (parser) => {
            debugger;
            parser.hooks.callAnyMember.for(functionName).tap('TranslationsPlugin', (expr) => {
                debugger;
```

The first `debugger` gets called and I check and `functionName` is "t", but the second debugger never gets called.

My guess is that it could be that webpack does this after the babel transpiling or something and the function is not called the same. But, in that case, I don't know what to do.

And, I can barely find good documentation for this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Same use case, same problem. Have you been able to proceed? The documentation on all the compiler/compilation/parser hooks is practically non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I know this was asked a long time ago, but I have encountered the same use case and the same problem and was able to solve it.

It's kinda obscure in the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/parser/#evaluatecallexpressionmember), but you could try using `evaluateCallMemberExpression` instead of `callAnyMember`.

```
parser.hooks.evaluateCallExpressionMember.for('t').tap('TranslationPlugin', (expression, param) => {
   // TODO - check that the call expression is actually belong to the right object
   // then collect the parameters...
});
```

It did the job for me after spending a few hours trying to reason with `call` and `callAnyMember` without success.

I think that the reason behind this small difference is that the value returned from the call for `t` is assigned to a variable rather than simply being a call to a function. So the code I'm trying to collect data for looks like this:

```
const label = i18next.t('someKey');
```

I did expect `callAnyMember` to work and I am still thinking it's an issue in `webpack` (I was using it with version `4.19.1`). But for now I'll stick with this solution